# When I hit the post request, in the rabbitMQ it is going unacked but I want my message to be acknowledged

Tags: rabbitmq

Basically when I hit the post request I want my message to be published to the queue in the RabbitMQ and it to be processed . But when I hit the post request it is going to the queue but going unacked. I have used IHostedService so that when I publish the message, the message will be consumed through the background process.

```
using EMS.Models;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using EMS.Models.Command;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


namespace EMS.RabbitMQ
{
        public class RabbitMqEmployeeConsumer : IHostedService, IDisposable
        {
            private readonly IMediator _mediator;
            private readonly IConnection _connection;
            private readonly IModel _channel;
            private readonly string _queueName = "employeeRequests";
            private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

            public RabbitMqEmployeeConsumer(IMediator mediator)
            {
                _mediator = mediator;
                _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
                _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

                _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _queueName, durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                    HandleMessage(ea,message);

                    //_channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
                };
                _channel.BasicConsume(queue: _queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
            }

            private void HandleMessage(BasicDeliverEventArgs ea,string message)
            {
                var command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddEmployeeCommand>(message);
                var result = _mediator.Send(command).Result;
                _channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
                Console.WriteLine("Message processed and data inserted into the database.");
            }

            public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask; 
            }

            public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                _channel.Dispose();
                _connection.Dispose();
                return Task.CompletedTask; 
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                _channel.Dispose();
                _connection.Dispose();
                _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your question by briefly describing your code's purpose - this saves time for readers, what you've tried, and the specific issue you're facing. Aim for a concise 1-2 sentence question. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question by briefly describing your code's purpose - this saves time for readers, what you've tried, and the specific issue you're facing. Aim for a concise 1-2 sentence question. Thanks!